# Is there a cross programming language string formatting?

Tags: string, formatting, string-formatting, printf

If there is, I am guessing, it should be sprintf formatting in C language. Is this right? Are same format values (like %d, %s) supported by all well-known programming languages? Or is it differs?

Comment: It's not entirely clear what you're asking here.  It's true that other languages offer a similar syntax to `sprintf` format strings (e.g. Java's [`Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html)).  But different languages have different semantics, features, and data-types, so clearly there cannot be a single "cross-lanaguge string formatting" facility...

Comment: The supported syntax differs; .NET's `string.Format` method (usable in C#, VB.NET, Boo, Nemerle, F#, ...) accepts a [vastly different syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), for example, enclosing parameter indices in curly braces.

Comment: There's a paradigm certainly and if you understand sprintf, delphi's format, or ruby's interpolation will cause you few problems. A cross platform standard, no.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth I was talking about primitive types, sorry for misleading.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No there isn't a cross platform standard, a pity but there you go. sprintf as the standard would I'm afraid come down to an arbitrary opinion, or perhaps one based on the prevalence of C based languages. Wouldn't be the "best" choice in my **opinion** that's for sure. :)